# SVM - Min square norm

Tags: optimization, normed-spaces, machine-learning

All Support Vector Machine litterature mentions that optimal hyperplane is found as:

max 1/∥x∥ (st. constraints) which translates directly to:

min ∥x∥ or equivalently min $ ∥x∥^2 $.

Here ([Minimizing square of a norm](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/296535/minimizing-square-of-a-norm)) it is explained why the previous statement holds true.

However, none of the sources on SVM explain why in practice we want to min $ ∥x∥^2 $ instead of $ ∥x∥ $.

Given that $ ∥x∥\ge0 $ by definition which is the practical reason for this transformation of the problem to a QP?

Example litterature on SVM:

1. http://cs229.stanford.edu/notes/cs229-notes3.pdf
2. http://alex.smola.org/papers/2003/SmoSch03b.pdf

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short explanation: by squaring the norm we turn the problem into [quadratic programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_programming), for which many efficient solvers are available.

The reason quadratic programming is special is that the gradient of a quadratic function is linear. In particular, the gradient of $\|x\|^2$ is simply $2x$. In contrast, the gradient of $\|x\|$ is the nonlinear function $\frac{x}{\|x\|}$, which is discontinuous at the origin. Whether or not you actually use the gradient of a function when minimizing it, chances are that the continuity of gradient (or lack of it) will affect the rate of convergence of your method.

Comment: Thank you. This seems to be a very reasonable explanation.